# jQuery validation engine doesn't seems to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm having tough time getting the **jQuery validation engine** plugin working.
It was working well before, but after I introduced this theme (usman.it/free-responsive-admin-template/).
The script **doesn't seems to be working**.
What might be wrong here?

Any suggestions are welcome (This is just a test form with only 1 input tag, but in reality there would be several).

**File**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>


    <script src="../js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#k").validationEngine();
        });



    </script>
            <div>
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Admins</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid sortable">
                <div class="box span12">
                    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
                        <h2><i class="icon-edit"></i> Add New Admin</h2>
                    </div>
                    <form action="#" id="k" method="post">
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Focused input</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused, validate[required] text-input" name="focusedInput" id="focusedInput" type="text" >
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="Send" class="btn btn-success">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/span-->

            </div><!--/row-->
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in F12 console?

Comment: @NikolayTalanov

Not sure about that.
I checked and couldn't find any errors.

Comment: I reconstructed all in jsfiddle and it works fine =/
http://jsfiddle.net/8YvbV/

Comment: @NikolayTalanov
Ah yes!
It works perfectly.
What might be the problem here mate. Any guess?

Comment: It's really hard to tell. Have you tried to move your script src validationEngine.js above validationEngine-en.js?

Just tried, it's not the cause...